# Python mock a method from a class that was not imported

Tags: python, python-unittest

Take this example, func_to_test_script.py

```
from module import ClassA

def func_to_test():
    instance_b = ClassA.method_a()
    foo = instance_b.method_b()
```

`method_a` returns an instance of class `ClassB`.

I want to mock the calls of methods `method_a` and `method_b`, so I do

```
@mock.patch("func_to_test_script.ClassA", ClassAMock)
@mock.patch("func_to_test_script.ClassB", ClassBMock)
def test_func_to_test(self):
    # test
```

I can do this with `ClassA` (that was imported in `func_to_test`'s file), but with `ClassB` I get the error

```
AttributeError: <module 'module' from 'func_to_test_script.py'> does not have the attribute 'ClassB'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it will really fail because `ClassB` is not defined nor imported in func_to_test_script.py. But even if it is, there is still no need to patch it because it wouldn't take effect anyways. Why? Because the instance of `ClassB` will come from the response of `ClassA`, which you already mocked.

What you can do is control it from the mock of `ClassA`:

```
@mock.patch("func_to_test_script.ClassA")
def test_func_to_test(self, mock_class_a):
    mock_class_a.method_a.return_value.method_b.return_value = "value of foo"
    ...
```

Comment: What if I dont want to mock "ClassA.method_a" and only want to mock "ClassB.method_b" and want to test assert_called_with on "method_b"?